# How to install a Hadoop plugin or patch?

Tags: hadoop, interface, patch, hadoop-plugins, pluggable

Does somebody knows how to install a Hadoop patch like things in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385 ?

I don't know what and how to override the original codes so that the pluggable interface can work.

Could anybody give me a hint?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general, not a Hadoop related problem...
You can apply .patch files using the **patch command** on your terminal. You can find help to that command with *patch --help* and *man patch*